# Oracle customized merge

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have two tables one is source and another one is target. The source table gets updated/refresh with external data source and we have a PL/SQL block which runs daily and updates/inserts the target table rows using Oracle's **merge** function.

Now we have a situation where a column (email) in the target table could get updated by some external source. Consequently, this email is being updated/overwritten by email of source table with the above mentioned PL/SQL's merge function.

Is there something in the merge function so that it only updates the rows in the target table if things other than the email have been changed. I am happy to add new column(s) into the source and target table if needed.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE INSERT_UPDATE_TARGET AS 

BEGIN
  merge into INTEGRATION_TARGET t
  using  v_merge vm 
  on (t.person_num = vm.person_num) 
  when matched then update set T.YEAR_START = VM.YEAR_START,
    T.SEMESTER_START = VM.SEMESTER_START,         
    T.SATAC_DATABASE_NAME = VM.SATAC_DATABASE_NAME,   
    T.STUDY_LEVEL = VM.STUDY_LEVEL,  
    T.REF_NUM = VM.REF_NUM,          
    T.SEX = VM.SEX,                    
    T.DATE_OF_BIRTH = VM.DATE_OF_BIRTH,         
    T.DATE_RECEIVED = VM.DATE_RECEIVED,
    T.TITLE = VM.TITLE,
    T.FAMILY_NAME = VM.FAMILY_NAME,
    T.GIVEN_NAME_1 = VM.GIVEN_NAME_1,
    T.STREET_NAME = VM.STREET_NAME,
    T.STREET_NAME_2 = VM.STREET_NAME_2,
    T.STREET_NAME_3 = VM.STREET_NAME_3,
    T.POSTAL_STATE = VM.POSTAL_STATE,
    T.POSTAL_TOWN = VM.POSTAL_TOWN,
    T.POSTAL_POSTCODE = VM.POSTAL_POSTCODE,
    T.COUNTRY = VM.COUNTRY,
    T.MOBILE = VM.MOBILE,
    T.EMAIL = VM.EMAIL
when not matched then insert (T.YEAR_START,
    T.SEMESTER_START,         
    T.SATAC_DATABASE_NAME,   
    T.STUDY_LEVEL,  
    T.REF_NUM,                
    T.PERSON_NUM,             
    T.SEX,                    
    T.DATE_OF_BIRTH,         
    T.DATE_RECEIVED,
    T.TITLE,
    T.FAMILY_NAME,
    T.GIVEN_NAME_1,
    T.STREET_NAME,
    T.STREET_NAME_2,
    T.STREET_NAME_3,
    T.POSTAL_STATE,
    T.POSTAL_TOWN,
    T.POSTAL_POSTCODE,
    T.COUNTRY,
    T.MOBILE,
    T.EMAIL
       ) 
    values(VM.YEAR_START,
    VM.SEMESTER_START,         
    VM.SATAC_DATABASE_NAME,   
    VM.STUDY_LEVEL,  
    VM.REF_NUM,                
    VM.PERSON_NUM,             
    VM.SEX,                    
    VM.DATE_OF_BIRTH,         
    VM.DATE_RECEIVED,
    VM.TITLE,
    VM.FAMILY_NAME,
    VM.GIVEN_NAME_1,
    VM.STREET_NAME,
    VM.STREET_NAME_2,
    VM.STREET_NAME_3,
    VM.POSTAL_STATE,
    VM.POSTAL_TOWN,
    VM.POSTAL_POSTCODE,
    VM.COUNTRY,
    VM.MOBILE,
    VM.EMAIL

    );
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not completely sure that I understand the question.  Do you simply want to not update the destination table's `email` column?  If something other than the email address changes in the source table and the destination table's email address is changed, are you guaranteed that the source email address is correct?

Comment: Do you have control of the 'other' applications which update the email address?  Do you have some way of knowing the last time that the merge process was run?

Comment: @JustinCave,for all the records in the Target table whose email has been already updated by external source, I don't want to re-update the email address whatever it might be in the source table.The rest of the information have to be updated in a normal way.

Comment: @Bob, Yes I have control to the external application and I can find when the last time that the merge process was run.

Answer (score 1):

Add a where clause to your update statement